# Access to your US Accounts internationally. ( direct deposit )

Tags: united-states, bank-account, international, atm

My wife and I are considering moving from the US to another country as our work gives us the flexibility to do our jobs remote.

One of the things we take for granted is access to our cash.  Is there a bank in the US that has an significant international footprint so that direct deposits can continue and we can access the cash?  Any recommendations or points to consider here would be appreciated.

Forgive me if this is not an appropriate question, please feel free to redirect me to another site if another is more appropriate.

Comment: These days with a international Master/Visa debit card you can access cash in any ATM world wide. Some countries allow you to withdraw in USD, some only local currency. If the question is which is cheapest, it is offtopic as we don't recommend specifics.

Comment: So it really doesn't matter whether the bank has global footprint or not.

Comment: @Dheer   As a noob, how do you know if a Visa or Mastercard is International?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wells Fargo, Citibank, US Bank, HSBC**. Any of the "big" Wall Street banks will have an international presence. What you will have to be weary of is whether or not they have branches in the country you are thinking of going to, and whether or not that country has English as a primary (or secondary) language - assuming you are not fluent in that language.

https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/banking/best-banks-international-travel/

I know the article says "travel", but think of what you're doing as an extended travel plan.

Comment: Will be bookmarking that site...